# How do I add <a> tags to a Django HTML Email template?

Tags: django, html-email

I'm trying to set up a view to reset passwords. The HTML email template works fine, until I add a anchor tag which causes the emails to no longer be sent. I'm not getting any error messages so I'm not sure what the problem is. Is it not possible to send hyperlinks in an email? I want to try and create a button in the email so that a user will be redirected to reset their password when they click on it.

in views.py:

```
class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
template_name = "accounts/password_reset.html"
email_template_name = "accounts/password_reset_email.html"
html_email_template_name = "accounts/password_reset_html_email.html"
subject_template_name = "accounts/password_reset_subject.txt"
success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:password-reset-done")
```

password_reset_html_email.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    {% autoescape off %}
    <div>
    
    <p><b>A password reset was requested for</b> {{ user.email }} If you did not request this, then disregard the email.
    To reset your password click on the link below.</p>

    <h1>HTML VERSION</h1>

    <a href="{% url 'accounts:password-reset-confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">Verify Email</a>    
    <p>
    The link will expire in 24 hours.
    If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
    window instead.
    </p>
    </div>
    {% endautoescape %}
</body>
</html>
```

url patterns:

```
app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "password-reset/",
        views.CustomPasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name="password-reset",
    ),
    path(
        "password-reset-done/",
        views.CustomPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name="password-reset-done",
    ),
    path(
        "password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/",
        views.CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name="password-reset-confirm",
    ),
    path(
        "password-reset-complete/",
        views.CustomPasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name="password-reset-complete",
    ),
]
```

Comment: Can you share your urlpatterns?

Comment: I've updated the post with the relevant url patterns

Comment: Can you try with this? `<a href="http://yourdomain.com{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">Verify Email</a>`

Comment: Thanks, I did something like this and it works for gmail, but not on outlook. I looked around and this might be something to do with using SendGrid, rather than an issue with Django.